# how to get the reviews in google places api and how to display the review message below of the ratings

Tags: google-places-api

I wrote application for find the particular place near by my position. I got rating from my application. How to get the reviews and review message for that particular places.

I got rating from this below line in my code

```
var ratings = '{"rating":"' + details.rating + '"}';
```

How to get the reviews from the Google API.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature. There is a feature request for this in the Places API issue tracker [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2477).
Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes, and to let us know you are interested in seeing it resolved.